# Mongodb with bash: Creating replica sets gets 'error command line: unknown option fork use --help for help'

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb

I noticed Windows is having this problem, but I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (with Bash), so I don't know what is going wrong.

Trying to set up my replica sets, I run the following command:

```
sudo bash < create_replica_set.sh
```

or

```
sudo bash create_replica_set.sh
```

But my output is this:

```
error command line: unknown option fork
use --help for help
error command line: unknown option fork
use --help for help
error command line: unknown option fork
use --help for help
```

Here is my `create_replica_set.sh` script:

```
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27020 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "2.log" --dbpath /data/rs2 --port 27018 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "3.log" --dbpath /data/rs3 --port 27019 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
```

My `/data/rs*` folders are already created.

Oddly, this works if I copy/paste directly into terminal:

```
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~/class/M101P/6week$ sudo mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27020 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 13128
all output going to: /home/lucas/Dropbox/class/M101P/6week/1.log
log file [/home/lucas/Dropbox/class/M101P/6week/1.log] exists; copied to temporary file [/home/lucas/Dropbox/class/M101P/6week/1.log.2014-03-18T09-35-37]
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

If it matters, here is my `/etc/mongo.conf` (I already tried adding `fork=true` at the end):

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

#port = 27017

# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal = true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:28017).
#nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options

# in master/slave replicated mongo databases, specify here whether
# this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com
# in replica set configuration, specify the name of the replica set
# replSet = setname 
fork=true
```

Comment: You can invoke bash script by saying: `./script.sh` OR `bash script.sh`

Comment: When I run `bash create_replica_set.sh` I get the same result (updated above). Interestingly, when I run `sudo ./create_replica_set.sh` I get the following:
`sudo: ./create_replica_set.sh: command not found`. Do you know why? I am positive that the file is in my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with how to use mongod, but since you said your commands will run when typed directly into the shell try changing your script to

```
sudo mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27020 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
sudo mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "2.log" --dbpath /data/rs2 --port 27018 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
sudo mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "3.log" --dbpath /data/rs3 --port 27019 --oplogSize 64 --smallfiles --fork
```

Then run

```
. create_replica_set.sh
```

This will run (or source) the script in the current shell instead of trying to execute the commands in a subprocess. So it will be just as if you typed them in one at a time. You wont want to do this with all your scripts but this seems to be a special case.

REGARDING THE COMMENTS:

If you are not able to run `./create_replica_set.sh`, this is probably because you didn't give it executable permissions.

Do

```
chmod +x create_replica_set.sh
```

On it first. And make sure you have `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the script.